# Nhibernate queries with join (or fetch) return duplicates

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I meet unexpected behavior and It's not clear for me. Of course I can use distinct, but what is a reason?

I have **entities** (fluent auto-mapping):

```
public class Ticket
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

Test **data** (1 ticket with 5 activities):

```
new Ticket { Id = 1, Activities = new List<Activity>
    {
        new Activity(), new Activity(), new Activity(), new Activity()
    };
```

The **query**:

```
var report = GetSessionFactory()
    .OpenSession()
    .QueryOver<Ticket>()
    .JoinAlias(ticket => ticket.Activities, () => activity)
    .List<Ticket>();
```

And I have the following **result**:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As you stand you are returning a cartesian product as you are joining a `one-to-many` table, in your case 1 x 5 rows. So if you want to go down this route then you will need to add `.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)`

Are you sure you don't want to load an activity and use the goodness of lazy loading to retrieve the Activities? In most cases this might be the more efficient way.

Somehing like:-

```
var ticket = session.QueryOver<Ticket>.Where(w => w.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
OR
var ticket = session.Get<Ticket>(1);
```

then you can just call simply

```
foreach(var activity in  ticket.Activities)
{
 // do something here....
}
```

Comment: I see. But what is a reason? Why NHibernate does not do it implicitly?

Comment: Pass.  That's a question for the nh development team.  To be honest lazy loading is your friend.

Comment: What is suggested is leading to SELECT N+1

Comment: make sure you have `batch-size` enabled and this does not lead to SELECT N+1